# What does this do : while((c= getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);

Tags: c++, eof, getchar, gets

```
while((c= getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

I was facing a problem by using gets() to enter strings. I found on google that it was keeping the value of '\n' in the input buffer. I searched here and found the above code to solve my problem. However I don't quite get the hold of it. What does this do ?? Anybody please enlighten me.

Comment: No, you need to study C++ by yourself and then post a question here

Comment: I changed `C++` tag to `C` tag as it\`s pure `C`, not a `C++`.

Comment: @Benio don't do that. As long as it's valid C++ code, it doesn't matter that it's also valid C. And sometimes the difference matters.

Answer (score 4):

An assignment in C++ will also yield the value being assigned. So `c= getchar()` is reading the next character from the file, and `(c= getchar()) != '\n'` is comparing that read character to the newline character. There's another test for the special `EOF` value, to make sure it doesn't keep trying to read once you reach the end of the file.

There's no statement between the `while` and the closing semicolon because nothing else needs to be done, you're throwing the input away.

Comment: So basically what it does is that after I input the string, it reads the string until it finds a new line character and EOF ie -1 ??

Comment: @gotolabeladi Until it finds a new line character ***or*** EOF.

Answer (score 2):

The code introduces a `while`-loop. Its exit condition assigns the integer `c` the value that `getchar()` returns, and checks whether it is equal to the newline character (`'\n'`) or `EOF`. If it is, the loop exits. If it isn't, the next character is extracted, and so on.

The code basically skips all characters until the next newline or `EOF` is reached. It is equivalent to:

```
for (;;)
{
    c = getchar(); // c has been declared elsewhere
    if (c == '\n' || c == EOF)
        break;
}
```

Comment: Yeah ! It's much easier to understand this way, than that which was condensed into a single line. +1

Comment: @gotolabeladi , You don't have enough rep to upvote/+1 but you can still accept it